# rank records according to vendors having most sales(Quantity*Price)

Tags: c#, sql-server

[image]

Mine is an Event Management related website.. On the Admin side i need the following : 
`VendorName` , `VendorPhoto`, `VendorPhone` , `VendorEmail` and `ServiceType(ServiceID)` based on the rankin of their sales(`Quantity`*`Price`) which is displayed in the `EventItem` table , i.e. :

A Vendor A(ServiceID : 1 , Service.Name:Florist) has a couple of  VendorItems in the table `VendorItem`(i.e. the product table) , similarly other Vendors will have their entries in the table `VendorItem` . When a user registers an event he will choose the `Quantity` and the product(i.e. the `VendorItem`) of a vendor.

then the query should check amongst all vendors of a particular type(e.g. : Florist,etc) , who has the most sales(top 3)/

This is the query which i have tried so far, but am not able to get the required results and i am confused in how to calculate the value `Quantity*Product` ?

```
  SELECT        TOP (3) tblVendor.VendorID, tblVendor.Name, tblVendor.Email, tblVendor.Phone, tblVendor.Address, tblVendor.UserName, tblVendor.Password, tblVendor.ServiceID, 
                         tblVendor.IsActive, tblVendor.Photo, tblEventItem.Quantity, tblEventItem.Price
FROM            tblEventItem CROSS JOIN
                         tblVendor INNER JOIN
                         tblEventService ON tblEventService.VendorID = tblVendor.VendorID
WHERE        (tblEventService.VendorID = 7)
ORDER BY ISNULL(tblEventItem.Quantity, 0) * ISNULL(tblEventItem.Price, 0) DESC
```

Comment: not working.
i tried this query

Comment: SELECT        TOP (3) tblVendor.VendorID, tblVendor.Name, tblVendor.Email, tblVendor.Phone, tblVendor.Address, tblVendor.UserName, tblVendor.Password, tblVendor.ServiceID, 
                         tblVendor.IsActive, tblVendor.Photo, tblEventItem.Quantity, tblEventItem.Price
FROM            tblEventItem CROSS JOIN
                         tblVendor INNER JOIN
                         tblEventService ON tblEventService.VendorID = tblVendor.VendorID
WHERE        (tblEventService.VendorID = 7)
ORDER BY ISNULL(tblEventItem.Quantity, 0) * ISNULL(tblEventItem.Price, 0) DESC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 3 tblEventItem.Quantity*tblEventItem.Price AS 'Sales',
             tblEventItem.VendorItemID,
             tblVendor.Name,
             tblVendor.Email,
             tblVendor.Phone,
             tblVendor.Photo

FROM tblEventService

INNER JOIN tblEventItem ON
            tblEventService.EventServiceID = tblEventItem.EventServiceID

INNER JOIN tblVendor ON
            tblEventService.VendorID = tblVendor.VendorID

WHERE tblEventService.ServiceID = @S_ID

ORDER BY 'SALES' DESC
```

This query will do the magic for you .

Here we make a column by multiplying the two columns : `tblEventItem.Quantity*tblEventItem.Price` and taking it into another column which is `SALES` .

Other selections are basic `INNER JOINS` as per the requirements in your `SELECT` query .

The `ORDER BY 'SALES' DESC` will give you the top 3 vendors with max sales!

Comment: `ORDER BY 'SALES' DESC`,is this Really Work??
i know that, we can't use the Alice name in group by/order by Claus.

Comment: @user3540365 : You should check again , because i am using this in my projects and it works perfectly well without any problem.

Answer (score 2):

use `Order By` with `(Quantity*Product) desc`

```
SELECT TOP (3) tblVendor.VendorID, 
tblVendor.Name, 
tblVendor.Email, 
tblVendor.Phone,
tblVendor.Address, 
tblVendor.UserName, 
tblVendor.Password,
tblVendor.ServiceID, 
tblVendor.IsActive, 
tblVendor.Photo, 
tblVendor.Name AS 'VendorName', 
tblVendor.Photo AS Expr1, 
tblVendor.Email AS Expr2,
tblVendor.Phone AS Expr3   
FROM    
tblVendor 
INNER JOIN
tblVendorItem 
ON 
tblVendor.VendorID = tblVendorItem.VendorID
WHERE  (tblVendorItem.VendorID = 8) order by 
(Isnull(tblVendorItem.Quantity,0)*Isnull(tblVendorItem.Product,0)) desc
```

Comment: seems like i have to use `tblEventService` table with inner join. @user3540365

Comment: yes, if `tblEventService ` contains the `Product` column.

Comment: SELECT        TOP (3) tblVendor.VendorID, tblVendor.Name, tblVendor.Email, tblVendor.Phone, tblVendor.Address, tblVendor.UserName, tblVendor.Password, tblVendor.ServiceID, 
                         tblVendor.IsActive, tblVendor.Photo, tblEventItem.Quantity, tblEventItem.Price
FROM            tblEventItem CROSS JOIN
                         tblVendor INNER JOIN
                         tblEventService ON tblEventService.VendorID = tblVendor.VendorID
WHERE        (tblEventService.VendorID = 7)
ORDER BY ISNULL(tblEventItem.Quantity, 0) * ISNULL(tblEventItem.Price, 0) DESC

Comment: operand data type varchar is invalid for multiply operator